# Do bank conflicts occur on non-GPU hardware?

Tags: c, opencl, cpu-cache, bank-conflict

This [blog post](http://devblogs.nvidia.com/parallelforall/efficient-matrix-transpose-cuda-cc/) explains how memory bank conflicts kill the transpose function's performance.

Now I can't but wonder: does the same happen on a "normal" cpu (in a multithreaded context)? Or is this specific to CUDA/OpenCL? Or does it not even appear in modern CPUs because of their relatively large cache sizes?

Comment: GPUs and CPUs access memory in the same way, and cache isn't magical. Transposing on a CPU will be slow too.

Comment: Yes, CPUs have cache bank conflicts as well. I've personally observed slow-downs of > 10x on an AMD Piledriver for writing 5 streams spaced out by the critical stride even though the data fits in L1 cache.

Comment: I admit that cache bank conflicts and false aliasing are different, but difficult to distinguish. So it's possible that I was hitting false aliasing instead of bank conflicts.

Comment: They definitely do suffer from bank conflicts, although it's an artifact of the exact micro-architecture discussed. see [here](http://www.realworldtech.com/haswell-cpu/5/) for e.g. about banking changes in Haswell vs. SandyBridge

Comment: @rubenvb: I removed the CUDA tag from this question for a reason - it has nothing to do with CUDA programming. Why did you re-add it?

Comment: @talonmies I didn't notice you removed it honestly. It was to give this question visibility with the people who might actually know the answer. This question has nothing to do with C or OpenCL either, per se, yet it does, because the people following those tags might know the answer. In fact, it has lots to do with CUDA programming, because I found the issue on a CUDA blog. But anyway, remove it if you feel strongly it shouldn't be there.

Comment: The transpose is a memory bound  O(n^2) operation. CPU cores are too fast. The "cores" of GPUs are much slower so the transpose should be more efficient on the GPU. Fast core CPUs need O(n^3) operations to compete. Intel will brag about O(n^3) operations like matrix multiplication but avoid O(n^2)  operations. The level4 cache in some Haswell processors will help CPUs compete.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There  have been bank conflicts  since the earliest vector processing CPUs from the 1960's
It's caused by interleaved memory  or multi-channel memory  access.

Interleaved memory access or MCMA  solves the problem to slow RAM access, by phasing access to
each word of memory from different banks or via different channels. But there is a side effect,  memory access from the same bank takes longer than accessing memory from the adjacent bank.

From Wikipedia on the 1980's Cray 2 http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cray-2

"Main memory banks were arranged in quadrants to be accessed at the same time, allowing programmers to scatter their data across memory to gain higher parallelism. The downside to this approach is that the cost of setting up the scatter/gather unit in the foreground processor was fairly high. Stride conflicts corresponding to the number of memory banks suffered a performance penalty (latency) as occasionally happened in power-of-2 FFT-based algorithms. As the Cray 2 had a much larger memory than Cray 1's or X-MPs, this problem was easily rectified by adding an extra unused element to an array to spread the work out"